# Come into the picture -- meaning

Tags: meaning

From The Godfather:

> They had assumed that it was another gang execution, and had
>   questioned hoodlums with records in the rackets and a history of
>   strong-arm. Since Vito had never been in trouble he never *came into the*
>   *picture*.

So, what is the meaning of that here? I haven't found that in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While

> **come into something**: To be an aspect of a situation.
>
> Example: The argument was over artistic freedom – money never came into it. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-into)

and

> **Picture**: [SINGULAR] a situation. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/picture_1)

I would clearly interpret

> Since Vito had never been in trouble he never came into the picture.

As this: Due to the fact that Vito (probably legally) didn't get into any trouble, he wasn't being involved in the investigation.

There're also a phrase that's almost an opposite to this in terms of meaning:

> **Out of the picture**: no longer involved in something [Again Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/out-of-the-picture)

Answer (score 1):

"In the picture" is a common idiom meaning "relevant to the conversation". I haven't seen The Godfather, so I don't understand the context, but I would assume it means

> Since Vito had never been in trouble *they assumed it wasn't him, so they didn't question him.*